# Нужна помощь с обработкой команд в библиотеке PyTelegramBotApi

Tags: python, telebot

В телеграм ботах ведь есть команды /command и !command. И если /command обрабатывается следующим образом:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['command'])
def some_func(message):
    Действие
```

То как обрабатывается !command?

Comment: проверять первый символ команды?

Comment: @Jack_oS а как?)

Comment: @bot.message_handler(func=message.text.startswith('!') and commands=['command']) как-то так попробуйте...

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую

Answer (score 0):

Вот рабочии код:

```
import telebot
import logging
from telebot import types

API_TOKEN = 'BOT TOKEN HERE'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)

logger = telebot.logger
telebot.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() in ["/command", "!command"])
def send_welcome(message):
    msg = bot.reply_to(message, "Привет!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.infinity_polling()
```

Удачи!

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]